# How do I turn off syntax highlighting for txt files in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, quotes

Notepad recently began applying a greyed-out color to anything in quotes in my txt files. I don't know what started this and I can't find way to undo it in the settings. How do I change it back?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Click on LANGUAGE -> N -> NORMAL TEXT
You may have somehow selected Java as the language setting of your documents.

You can also set the default by going to:
SETTINGS -> PREFERENCES -> NEW DOCUMENT -> DEFAULT TEXT -> DEFAULT LANGUAGE and set that to "Normal Text".

Answer (score 0):

You could check in Settings -> Styler Configurator -> Global Styles.

Go here for more info: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Marking_And_Highlighting